# Building a URL using Visual Basic

Tags: excel, vba

My name is lee, and I'm new on here. I'm very experienced in Excel, and most aspects of Office, but not so much in VBA.

I have embedded a local map using an API in excel, and want to plot multiple postal codes. I have this working up to 23 postal codes using a Hyperlink and Concatenate in the same formula to build the URL. After 23 postal codes, the formula result exceeds 255 characters, so that's where I fail.

I need one solution - either a way to work around the limit (without using a 3rd party url shortener), or by building the entire URL in VBA. My button launches the formulated url from cell A1, but when it exceeds 255 characters, I assume I will need the button to run the url directly from within VBA?

Anyhow, I'm sure I've probably missed out some vital info, so please, if you think are able to help, ask me and I'll give as much extra detail as possible.

Comment: Can you show your workings?

Comment: I think you need to show an example of input/output + the code you've already tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the long string in lets say 2 variables and then use them in VBA to concatenate it with your formula.

An example of what you have would be better.

Comment: I don't know how to add a longer comment on here. Like I said, newbie.

Comment: I want to create a "http://www.google.com" start address with b2, then b3, then b4, etc added to the url, with a bit of text between each cell, such as "&"